# What's the meaning of "降らば" in this sentence "降らば降れと天をにらみつけ"?

Tags: grammar

When listening to amazarashi's song "つじつま合わせに生まれた僕等" on Youtube, the first "誦読" part has such a sentence "降らば降れと天をにらみつけ."

Intuitively, It sounds like a causative-conditional conjugation to me and means something like "if it befalls on us." But I'm not sure. Can anybody out there shed some light on it?

Many thanks.

[image]

Edit:

First of all, thanks @naruto for the reply. And after digging around for a while, I found 2 pieces of information that might also be useful to future readers of this post.

Here are the links for reference: <[link1](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B0)> and <[link2](http://sanpunkobun.seesaa.net/article/300682150.html)>

By the way, I like this tiny part of the info:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

降らば降れ is the same as 降るなら降れ, but said using the grammar of classical Japanese. A literal translation of this is "(O Rain,) if (you) fall, fall!". A message like "Rain cannot stop me" is implied.

Conditional forms worked a little differently in classical Japanese. The conditional ば attached to the 未然 (aka irrealis or pre-nai) form of the verb. See: [using 未然形 and 已然形 with conditional ば](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/80193/5010) and [寄らば from 寄らば大樹の陰](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/52173/5010)

In modern Japanese, this is a pattern that is used in stilted sentences and has an implication of "let it go" or "I don't care". Similar expressions include:

- 死なば死ね: Let them die if necessary; I don't mind if they/you/I die
- 笑わば笑え: If they laugh at me, let them do so (I don't care)

Comment: Are those fixed expression, or can the ~あstemば~えstem form be used with any verb?

Comment: @Mauro 死なば死ね and 笑わば笑え may be called fixed expressions, 未然形+ば is not completely dead, so you may occasionally see it used with any godan verb, mainly for the purpose of archaism. It can be used when [～む](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5396/5010), せよ and so on can be used naturally (magic spell, dragon's language, Shakespeare, ...).